# [VBA]Lotus Notes Inbox order

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I'm using VBA to crawl e-mails in Note's Inbox.

I conferred the code at the bottom of this page, made a module that
fetch e-mails' subjects and delete if the subject satisfies the certain condition.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?37541-Move-Lotus-Notes-mail-to-a-folder-in-Lotus-Notes-through-VBA

Basically, the macro is fetching e-mails from oldest to latest ones, but at times  the fetching order becomes backwards.

```
Set NView = NMailDb.GetView(sNotesSourceFolder) 
Set NDoc = NView.GetFirstDocument
```

Is this note's view getting method sometimes fetches e-mail backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of GetFirstDocument/GetNextDocument has changed over time, but I believe the current behavior is that it returns documents in the current sort order of the view. Since users can re-sort the view, that will affect the order.

Comment: It's quite strange even if I haven't re-sorted the view in notes' inbox.